# Google Font while bold does not render spaces for NumberFormat in Flutter app

Tags: flutter, google-fonts

I have an issue where the spaces between the thousands do not render with Lato (and a few other fonts) when bolded.

[image]

You can see the spaces between each set of three zeros which is what I want but they do not render for the other lines.

My font configuration is:

```
  fonts:
    - family: SourceSansPro
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
    - family: PublicSansBlack
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/PublicSans-Black.ttf
    - family: RobotoSlab
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/RobotoSlab-Regular.ttf
          weight: 400
        - asset: fonts/RobotoSlab-Medium.ttf
          weight: 500
    - family: Lato
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Lato-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
```

What is weird is that `PublicSansBlock` renders right when the weight is `FontWeight.normal` but not the others. And it's the same font source as I am only loading in one weight. Could this be a bug with `TextStyle`?

The value is `100 000 000` formatted via `new NumberFormat('###,###,###,###', 'fr')` but I suspect it's unrelated to this as I see it working for another font and non-bold.